# Read response of curl command in shell script

Tags: shell, curl

I am writing a shell script in which I need to work on the response of an api. I called the api using curl command and trying to get its response in shell so that I can loop over response and print it. But I am not able to get the response. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(curl "https://example.com/test")
echo "test"
RESP=`echo $result | grep -oP "^[^a-zA-Z0-9]"`

echo "$RESP"
```

I am getting empty response after test. Can somebody help me over this ?

Comment: Try adding double quote in `echo "${result}"`...

Comment: @sungtm I did the above while grep and it has no difference

Comment: @Amandeepkaur, SSA(greetings), could you please check if your variable is not empty on first place? Do a `echo "$result"` and let us know then.

Comment: Sat Sri Akal @RavinderSingh13, I did echo "$result" just after curl statement and its empty. If I replace curl with wget then i get a file saved in my system which is having correct json response. Do I need to pass some headers with the curl ?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur, Cool so now we cleared first step of troubleshooting, we know our first variable itself DO NOT have any value so innocent grep can't do anything there, lemme check on something and get back to you here.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur, Ok I believe you are on right path for saving its output to a variable using `$(...)` syntax. How about only running curl command with url to your terminal once and see what output are you getting? This will make sure either curl is running fine from your box or not, lemme know on same.

Comment: BTW, generally, `set -x` gives you logs that are more comprehensive and conclusive than `echo`ing your values does. `echo`'s output is often misleading, *especially* when used without adequate quotes, as described briefly in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) and comprehensively in [Stephane's excellent Unix StackExchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113). The APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) are also enlightening.

Comment: ...you want grep to give you strings that *aren't* alphanumeric as results? Do you have reason to believe there will be any non-whitespace result at all? (Or that you're using a version of `grep` that supports the nonstandard `-P` argument at all)?

Comment: (the code in the question would make much more sense to me if you took out the second `^`, or at least contained an explanation of why you want it there).

Answer (score 2):

Try this syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash
result="$(curl -s 'https://example.com/test')"
echo "result: '$result'"
RESP=$(echo "$result" | grep -oP "^[^a-zA-Z0-9]")
echo "RESP:'$RESP'"
```

Explanation:

- We store in $result the result of the page curled (-s removes the status of download and things that don't belong to the page)
- We echo the content of $result between quotes, to check what we got.
- We store the content of that grep command (what are you looking for btw? please leave a comment if you need Regex help)
- We echo the content of $RESP between quotes, to check what we got.

Comment: What's the value to the literal single-quotes? (I worry that their use leads people to assume that content has been quoted/sanitized adequately to make it safe to copy-and-paste into another command line, which isn't generally true -- as `"'$foo'"` only evaluates to the literal content of variable `foo` should that content not contain any literal single-quote characters).

Comment: I generally use single quotes when I check the contents of variables to differentiate line returns, single space ' ', empty variable '', etc. It's just a quick trick to see if your variable contains something, and by no mean a best practice like testing with -z, indeed! :D